# Sort records by; future ASC, past DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort records as follows:

1. Future/present events ASC
2. Past events DESC

So first today, then tomorrow, until there are no more future records. 
Then I want to show the past events, but the latest first.

So far I've found a solution for the first point:

```
ORDER BY (
    CASE WHEN ev.StartDate < CURDATE()
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
     END) ASC, ev.StartDate ASC
```

But the issue with this query is that all posts are ordered ASC, including the past posts (which need to be DESC).

How do I combine this in the `CASE`?

Comment: You can use the date difference and multiply with -1 to change the ordering of past/present.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a slightly more complex `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (ev.StartDate < CURDATE()),
         (case when ev.StartDate > CURDATE() then ev.StartDate end) ASC,
         (case when ev.StartDate < CURDATE() then ev.StartDate end) DESC
```

You could actually do this with two clauses:

```
ORDER BY greatest(ev.StartDate, CURDATE()) DESC,
         least(ev.StartDate, CURDATE()) ASC
```

But I think the first version is clearer in its intention.

Answer (score 2):

I find this most straight forward, without needing complex conditional syntax:

first one ranks future before past, second one orders the future ASC, third one orders the past DESC

(second and third ones are interchangeable)

```
ORDER BY
  (date < CURDATE()) ASC,
  (greatest(date, CURDATE()) ASC,
  (least(date, CURDATE()) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! I've have already applied and patched the chosen code, but will revisit this when I have a chance/need.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN (CURDATE() > ev.StartDate)
THEN datediff(CURDATE(),ev.StartDate )  --Past, older date bigger differ
ELSE datediff(ev.StartDate , CURDATE()+100) END  --Future, differ from a more futrue date
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and found another way

```
ORDER BY (CURDATE()>ev.StartDate) ASC, ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ev.StartDate))
```